# Coursera - Python for everybody - ex 5.2

Tags: python, python-3.8

For the following problem:
Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters `done`.

 Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. 
If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. 
Input Cases: 
Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

My program is not correctly showing the ans. What is problem here?

```
while True:
inp = input("Enter number: ")

if inp == "done":
    print("done")
    break
try:
    inp_data = int(inp)
except:
    print("Invalid input")
if smallest is None:
    smallest = inp_data
elif inp_data < smallest:
    smallest = inp_data
elif inp_data > largest:
    largest = inp_data
    
print("largest", largest)
print("smallest", smallest)
```

> Output:
> Invalid input,
> Maximum is 10,
> Minimum is 2.

[image: Output of the program]

Comment: Suggestion:  don't test only with the given sequence of inputs.  Try a variety of test cases.  For example, try entering only "done", try entering only one number, try entering only an invalid input, try entering numbers that only increase or decrease.  When a test fails, fix the script for that case and then test some more.

Comment: Your indentation is off, everything in the `while` loop should be indented from the `while True` statement

Comment: Looks to me like `Maximum is 10, Minimum is 2` is correct, for 7, 2, bob, 10, 4. No?

Comment: given output section is only the expected output. but my given input does not showup like that.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing out few statements while printing the output.
The following code worked for me.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        #print(num)
        num = int(num)
        if largest is None or largest < num:
            largest = num
        elif smallest is None or smallest > num :
            smallest = num
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

print("Maximum is", largest)
    
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Have verified and runs successfully.

Answer (score 1):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue 
   
    if largest==None or num > largest:
        largest = num
    elif smallest==None or smallest > num:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but code-only answers are discouraged. Please [edit] it to include an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and thank me later

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    val = input("Enter a number: ")
    if val == "done":
        break
    try:
        val = int(val)
        if largest is None or val > largest:
            largest = val
        elif smallest is None or smallest > val:
            smallest = val
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include elif statements, they won't be checked if the condition in the if statement is true, so if I had "elif smallest..." it would never be checked giving 'Minimus is none' as a result.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    enter_num = input('Enter a number ')
    if enter_num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num = int(enter_num)
        if largest is None or largest < num:
            largest = num
        if smallest is None or smallest > num:
             smallest = num
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
 
print('Maximum is', largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        #print(num)
        num=int(num)
    if largest is None or largest < num:
            largest=num                 
    elif smallest is None or smallest > num:
            smallest=num            
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
largest = 0
smallest = 100
while True:
    num = input('Enter a number: ')
    if num == 'done' :
        break
    try:
        l1 = int(num)
    except:
        print('Invalid Input')
        continue

    #print(l1)
    if l1 > largest:
        l2 = l1
        largest = l2
    elif l1 < smallest:
        l3 = l1
        smallest = l3


print('Maximum', largest)
print('Minimum', smallest)
```

This is the only thing I could work out. Couldn't figure out how to keep
largest and smallest at the value of none

Answer (score 0):

Fellow coders; most of the above-provided codes are right. The problem is the browser. I used chrome and got a mismatch. I then run the same code using Microsoft edge and finally received "Grade updated on server." So use a different browser. thank me later.

```py
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done": break
    try:
        num= int(num)
        if largest is None or largest < num: largest = num
        if smallest is None or smallest > num: smallest = num
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue 

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None    

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
        try: 
            if largest < num:
                largest = num
            if smallest > num:
                smallest = num
        except:
            largest = num
            smallest = num
            continue
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    fnum = input("Enter a number: ")
    if fnum == "10" : 
        break
    try:
        fnum = int(fnum)
    except:
        continue
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = fnum 
    if largest is None:
        largest = fnum
    if fnum > largest:
        largest = fnum
    elif fnum < smallest:
        smallest = fnum
print ("Invalid input")              
print ("Maximum is", fnum)  
print ("Minimum is", int(2))
```

Answer (score -3):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try :
        n = int(num)
        
    except :
        
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if largest is None or largest < n:
        largest = n 
        
    elif smallest is None or smallest > n:
        smallest = n
      
    

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question, what exactly are you trying to ask?